# permission and timeout issues connecting to local northwind database in C# entity data model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

i am trying to connect to the northwind database in a C# project (entity data model). i am running on my own machine as admin, and have permissions both as admin and as user Gary\PC-Gary

In the Connection Properties dialog box , when i locate the northwind datbase, and double click it
i get the following error message:

**Northwind
you don't have permission to open this file.
Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission**

i  detach the database from SQL Server (on the understanding that C# 2010 will not allow a user instance to connect to a database that is currently in use)

I seem to be making progress, because now, when I browse to the database file, i  seem to get past the connection issues, and CAN pull up the filename. 
HOWEVER, when i attempt to test the connection (or create the EDMX model), i get the following error message. i am using windows authentication.

**a network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing 
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error:26 - Error Locating Server/instance specified)**

i have verified that the instance is running in SQL Server Configuration manager and in SSMS. does sql server have to be configured to allow remote connections to access a database on your own machine?? how would this be done?

Comment: Can you show the connection string , maybe you can mask the credentials and all sensitive data?

Answer (score 0):

Found a suggestion here by Peja Tao. Maybe that will help.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cdc71eb-6929-4ae8-a5a8-c1f461bd61b4/provider-sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified